# Text Alignment on Custom UI Button

Tags: ios

I have to make a custom button. The problem is that the text on the button is not being center aligned.
I make the text label of the same frame size as the `UIButton` frame.
And the text alignment of text label is center.

But it is not exactly in the center. It is on right side.

Comment: Probably just an error in your code. Post it here, and we will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the textLabel's frame in the following way:

```
textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: Actually I had to set the label just 1,2 pixel on left side from center .

Answer (score 0):

If you use cocos2d try this:

```
//Take Size of the screen
CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
```

and

```
//puts the label in the center of the screen
label.position = ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had to set the label just 1,2 pixel on left side from center..

I just got my issue resolve by using this ..

[okButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
        [okButton setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop];
        [okButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(13.0,27.0, 0.0, 0.0)];